# Prove/explain that the time complexity of the algorithm is O(h+k)

Tags: algorithm, tree, time-complexity, pseudocode, asymptotic-complexity

Prove/explain that the time complexity of the given algorithm is O(h+k). Where h is the height of the tree and k is the number of nodes in range between x and y (inclusive).

I know that if k=0 (no items in range) then it the algorithm simply traverses through the height of the tree thus O(h). I also know if a node is in the range it recurs to both of its children as opposed to just one of them. But this seems to have a doubling effect, so I am confused on how to prove/explain this.

```
INRANGE-TREE-WALK (v, x, y)
  if v != NIL
    if v.key < x
      INRANGE-TREE-WALK(v.right, x, y)
    else if v.key 〈= y
      print v.key
      INRANGE-TREE-WALK (v.left, x, y)
      INRANGE-TREE-WALK (v.right, x, y)
    else
      INRANGE-TREE-WALK(v.left, x, y)
```

Comment: Some human-readable explanation of the algorithm is highly appreciated. Also, it seems like the tree you are traversing is a binary search tree, but it's not outlined anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the tree is a binary search tree.

You could look at the depth of the current node with which the function is called, and then notice that for any given depth, never more than one node *v* with that depth is visited for which `v.key < x`.

Although that can happen many times on different depths, the claim is that this will never happen more than once at the *same* depth in the tree.

Assume for a moment this claim is false, and that at one specific depth *d* in the tree the algorithm visits two nodes *a* and *b*, and it finds that both `a.key < x` and `b.key < x`. Let's also choose *a* and *b* such that `a.key <= b.key`, i.e. *a* is at the left of *b*.

First, notice that the only way to visit both *a* and *b* is to first visit a common ancestor *p* of these nodes, for which we have `x <= p.key <= y`. Otherwise there is no way to walk along two different branches down the tree.

But since this is a binary search tree, all nodes *v* in the right subtree below *p* have values with `v.key >= P.key` and by consequence `v.key >= x`. This is also true for node *b*. But that is in contradiction with the premise that `b.key < x`.

So, we have proof that the function will not be called for two nodes on the same level and have `v.key < x` for both of them. By consequence this condition can only be found true *h* times in the total execution of the algorithm.

The same conclusion can be drawn for the case `v.key > y`.

How many times will `x <= p.key <= y` be true? As the algorithm will never visit the same node twice (as it only visits children of any visited node), the number of times that this condition is true is equal to *k*.

Remains the number of times that `v == NIL`. This can never be more than the number of visited nodes plus one.

Add all of this together and we arrive at a number of individual function calls that is not more than *2(2h + k)+1*, and given that the execution of one function call -- excluding the recursive calls -- is constant, we get a time complexity of *O(h+k)*.